# Is it possible for Webpack (with plugins) to minify my CSS files, place it in my dist folder, and add a tag to index.html

Tags: css, webpack, minify

I would like to end up with a CSS file that is a merged and minified version of my development environments standard CSS files.  With a hashed name based on the content of the file which is automatically added as a  tag in my resulting index.html file in my distribution folder.

Is this possible? I assume it is since I've gotten Webpack 4 to do just about everything else I've needed it to do.  If it is, how would I go about it?

Mind you, it has to be set up this way. I'm not allowed to use import statements or the like in my JS.

I have tried playing with the Mini Css Extract plugin and Optimize CSS Assets Webpack plugin to see if they could do what I want, but I'm likely doing something wrong as I never get any output file ( I know it wouldn't give me a modified index.html, but having the CSS file would be a start at least).

My current file structure is basically:
'mainFolder'/public/css <- the src css folder,
'mainFolder'/dist/css <- the dist folder where I would like to put the minified file

My config is currently set up like thus:

```
    const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = { 
    entry: [
        './public/js/app.js',
        './public/js/filters/weekday.js',
        './public/js/filters/dial-in.js',
        './public/js/filters/time.js',
        './public/js/filters/group-member.js',
        './public/js/filters/bool-to-icon.js',
        './public/js/filters/date-format.js',
        './public/js/filters/time-format.js',
        './public/js/services/main.js',
        './public/js/configs/config.js',
        './public/js/controllers/main.js',
        './public/js/pages/calendar/controller.js',
        './public/js/pages/company/view/controller.js',
        './public/js/pages/company/edit/controller.js',
        './public/js/pages/group-meeting/create/controller.js',
        './public/js/pages/group-meeting/detail/controller.js',
        './public/js/pages/group-meeting/view/controller.js',
        './public/js/pages/group-meeting-calendar/controller.js',
        './public/js/pages/login/controller.js',
        './public/js/pages/meeting-link/view/controller.js',
        './public/js/pages/meeting-link/edit/controller.js',
        './public/js/pages/meeting-link/detail/controller.js',
        './public/js/pages/user/view/controller.js',
        './public/js/pages/user/edit/controller.js',
        './public/js/lib/angular-semantic-ui.min.js'
    ],
    output: {
        filename: 'js/[contenthash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: 'dist'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map ',
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'], {

        }), 
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Zenvite',
            template: './public/templates/index.html',
            filename: 'templates/index.html'
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            //{ from: 'public/css', to:'css'},
            { from: 'public/media', to:'media'},
            { from: 'public/js/pages', to: 'js/pages', ignore: [ '*.js' ]},
            { from: 'public/templates/app.html', to: 'templates'}
        ]),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'app.css',
            chunkFilename: '[contenthash].css',
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                          // you can specify a publicPath here
                          // by default it use publicPath in webpackOptions.output
                          publicPath: '../public'
                        }
                    },
                    "css-loader"
                ]
            }
        ]

    },
    optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        styles: {
          name: 'styles',
          test: /\.css$/,
          chunks: 'all',
          enforce: true
        }
      }
    }
  },
};
```

Again the optimal result would be having something like [contenthash].css with merged and minified versions of my standard CSS and if possible an added  tag in my index.html file.
So far I've got nothing of the sort (except copying the standard files over to the dist directory)

Thanks in advance for any help and if I can answer any questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, when my supervisor realized the import statement was stripped out during compile they allowed it. So we went using that route to achieve what we want.  Bellow is ultimately what we went with

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = { 
    entry: [
        './public/js/app.js',
        './public/js/filters/weekday.js',
        './public/js/filters/dial-in.js',
        './public/js/filters/time.js',
        './public/js/filters/group-member.js',
        './public/js/filters/bool-to-icon.js',
        './public/js/filters/date-format.js',
        './public/js/filters/time-format.js',
        './public/js/services/main.js',
        './public/js/configs/config.js',
        './public/js/controllers/main.js',
        './public/js/pages/calendar/controller.js',
        './public/js/pages/company/view/controller.js',
        './public/js/pages/company/edit/controller.js',
        './public/js/pages/group-meeting/create/controller.js',
        './public/js/pages/group-meeting/detail/controller.js',
        './public/js/pages/group-meeting/view/controller.js',
        './public/js/pages/group-meeting-calendar/controller.js',
        './public/js/pages/login/controller.js',
        './public/js/pages/meeting-link/view/controller.js',
        './public/js/pages/meeting-link/edit/controller.js',
        './public/js/pages/meeting-link/detail/controller.js',
        './public/js/pages/user/view/controller.js',
        './public/js/pages/user/edit/controller.js',
        './public/js/lib/angular-semantic-ui.min.js'
    ],
    output: {
        filename: 'js/app.[contenthash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: 'dist'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map ',
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'], {

        }), 
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Zenvite',
            template: './public/templates/index.html',
            filename: 'templates/index.html'
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            //{ from: 'public/css', to:'css'},
            { from: 'public/media', to:'media'},
            { from: 'public/js/pages', to: 'js/pages', ignore: [ '*.js' ]},
            { from: 'public/templates/app.html', to: 'templates'}
        ]),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'css/app.[contenthash].css'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                'css-loader',
            ],
        }]
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                cache: true,
                parallel: true,
                sourceMap: true, // Must be set to true if using source-maps in production
        }),

            new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
        ]
   }
};
```